# No component "RNSVGPath" in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm adding a graphs library to my react native project:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pathjs-charts

and i'm using storybook, 
every time i'm trying to see the charts i get an error saying
"No component found for view with name "RNSVGPath"

i tried linking the repositories but that doesn't help
any idea on how to fix it ?

here is my story:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Bar } from 'react-native-pathjs-charts'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
  },
});

export default class Welcome extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `Bar (Column) - Basic`,
  });

  styles = {
    wrapper: {
      flex: 1,
      padding: 24,
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    header: {
      fontSize: 18,
      marginBottom: 18,
    },
    content: {
      fontSize: 12,
      marginBottom: 10,
      lineHeight: 18,
    },
  };

  showApp(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.props.showApp) this.props.showApp();
  }

  render() {
    let data = [
      [{
        "v": 49,
        "name": "apple"
      }, {
        "v": 42,
        "name": "apple"
      }],
      [{
        "v": 69,
        "name": "banana"
      }, {
        "v": 62,
        "name": "banana"
      }],
      [{
        "v": 29,
        "name": "grape"
      }, {
        "v": 15,
        "name": "grape"
      }]
    ]


    let options = {
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      margin: {
        top: 20,
        left: 25,
        bottom: 50,
        right: 20
      },
      color: '#2980B9',
      gutter: 20,
      animate: {
        type: 'oneByOne',
        duration: 200,
        fillTransition: 3
      },
      axisX: {
        showAxis: true,
        showLines: true,
        showLabels: true,
        showTicks: true,
        zeroAxis: false,
        orient: 'bottom',
        label: {
          fontFamily: 'Arial',
          fontSize: 8,
          fontWeight: true,
          fill: '#34495E',
          rotate: 45
        }
      },
      axisY: {
        showAxis: true,
        showLines: true,
        showLabels: true,
        showTicks: true,
        zeroAxis: false,
        orient: 'left',
        label: {
          fontFamily: 'Arial',
          fontSize: 8,
          fontWeight: true,
          fill: '#34495E'
        }
      }
    }

    return (
      <View style={this.styles.wrapper}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
          <Bar data={data} options={options} accessorKey='v'/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

Welcome.defaultProps = {
  showApp: null,
};

Welcome.propTypes = {
  showApp: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Thnx